# Delete row in Sqlite database using Python Flask and jQuery

Tags: python, jquery, flask

I can't get this to work. I simply need users to be able to delete rows in a table using a button. I don't want the UI to reset or scroll so I am using ajax via jQuery.

In app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route('/delete', methods=['POST'])

def delete():
    con = sqlite3.connect('ships.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('DELETE FROM `liners` WHERE liner_ip = "' + request.form['id'] + '"')
    cur.commit()
    con.close()
```

In index.html:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( 'a.delete' ).click( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/delete',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});

<form action="/delete" method="post" role="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{row['liner_ip']}}">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delete">DELETE</a>
</form>
```

The row does not get deleted and the response code is 200. So I don't know what the issue is. I can confirm that the form gets populated properly and the ajax request is made.

Can anyone point me to a sample that does this?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a `form`, simply create a `input` field. When the button is selected, the `ajax` can make a `GET` request:

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route("/")
@app.route('/delete')
def delete():
  con = sqlite3.connect('ships.db')
  cur = con.cursor()
  cur.execute('DELETE FROM `liners` WHERE liner_ip = "' +  request.args.get('id')+ '"')
  cur.commit()
  con.close()
  return flask.jsonify({'success':"True"})
```

Then, in the `html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div class='wrapper'> <!--Need wrapper for anchoring button click -->
        <input type="hidden" name="id" class='input_row' value="{{row['liner_ip']}}">
        <button class='delete_row'>DELETE</button>
      </div>
    </body>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.wrapper').on('click', '.delete_row', function(){
          var val = $('.input_row').val();
          $.ajax({
            url: "/suggestions",
            type: "get",
            data: {id: val},
            success: function(response) {
              $('.input_row').val('');
            },

          });
        });
      });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ajax1234, but using HTTP GET for a DELETE function is an anti-pattern. GET's should only be used for non-destructive (i.e. idempotent) operations. Any way to do this via POST?